# Permission to files owned by group denied

Tags: permissions, groups

I think the easiest way to describe is using these pictures:

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCZ4d.png)

I also tested using

> chmod -R a+rw minecraft2

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the group execute permission set on minecraft2 directory. Execute permission is required  in order to be able to `cd` into directory.

You can fix this by executing the following command:

```
chmod g+x minecraft2
```

Comment: That's odd to me, but it works.
Thank You :)

Comment: Execute permission has a different meaning for directories. This might seem confusing if you are not too familiar with Unix permissions.

Comment: Good to know, I think I should read a bit about it.